# How to get the pid of command running with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sudo

I am trying to get the pid of this command.

```
sudo -b tcpdump -i eth0 port 80 -w eth0.pcap
```

Comment: I am running several tcpdump command like, so i want to do someting like $!(last command pid).

Comment: `ps aux | grep sudo | tail -n 1` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `$!` to get the pid of the last background process (which will be the sudo in this case), and `ps --ppid` to find out about its children.  So for example:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 port 80 -w eth0.pcap &
$ ps --ppid $! -o pid=
16772
$ ps --pid 16772
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
16772 pts/3    00:00:00 tcpdump
```

If you're doing this in a script, you might want to use a `sleep 1` between the `sudo` and `ps` to ensure that the child gets started.

Note that if you really must use the `-b` flag to sudo, this won't work, as that will cause sudo to do an extra fork and immediately exit, losing the connection between child and parent (the tcpdump command will get reparented to init), which means you'll have no easy way of distinguishing the child from any other similar command.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way to do it:

```
sudo -u username sh -c "echo \$\$ > /tmp/my_pid/file; exec my_command" &
```

The other answers here rely on grepping ps output.  If there's multiple tcpdump commands running, you may accidentally grep the wrong pid.  This gets the actual pid and puts it in a file.

Here's an example running tcpdump as root:

```
 $ sudo -u root sh -c "echo \$\$ > /tmp/tcpdump.pid; exec tcpdump -i en3 -w eth0.pcap" &
[1] 37201
tcpdump: listening on en3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
$ sudo kill `cat /tmp/tcpdump.pid`
6212 packets captured
6243 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
[1]+  Done                    sudo -u root sh -c "echo \$\$ > /tmp/tcpdump.pid; exec tcpdump -i en3 -w eth0.pcap"
$
```

Comment: This does the Right Thing(r).

Comment: Just in case someone like me is chasing an issue getting the "wrong" pid: `; my_command` will give you the PID of sudo, but `; exec my_command` will give you the PID of the process you're looking for. `sudo -u username sh -c "echo \$\$ > /tmp/my_pid/file; exec my_command" &` < don't forget the `exec` unless you also want to spend 10min tempted to use `$PID + 1`

Answer (score 4):

for this purpose I will enter

`sudo gvim &`

`ps aux | grep gvim`

supplies me with the following output

`root     11803  0.0  0.0  12064  2776 pts/3    T    12:17   0:00 sudo gvim`

to grab only the pID i prefer to use awk

`ps aux | awk '/gvim/ {print $2}'`

which would return simply

> > 11803

I could kill the program from `awk` as well by piping a kill command to bash

`ps aux | awk '/gvim/ {print "sudo kill -9 "$2}' | bash`

Comment: This will give your more answers if there are any other gvim processes running at the same time.

Comment: yes, his comment to his original question was not written when I answered this question. I'll amend my answer when I have additional time.

Comment: Definitely recommend pgrep with this strategy, saves a lot of effort

Answer (score 0):

The `-o` option to `ps` lets you choose what fields to display.  Of those fields, you can show things like cumulative cpu time (`cputime`), elapsed time (`etime`), and start time (`lstart`).  You can also sort on a field using `--sort`.  So a solution for you could be:

```
ps -eo pid,command,lstart --sort lstart | grep 'sudo -b tcpdump' | tail -1
```

You don't even need to tell `ps` to display the field you want to sort by.  `man ps` for more details.